# Python, how Read File hex and Shift It

Tags: python, hex, decimal

before submit new question i search about this but i was unsuccessful in find a good answer , i want read some byte of a file with any type extentions , i want read to hex and shift it to left or right then overwrite it . i can read 4 byte with this code :

```
FILE = open(dst,"r+b")
FILE.seek(1,0)
byte = FILE.read(4)
my_hex = binascii.hexlify(byte)
```

result:

```
sample my hex: af5f3fee
```

now i need to shift it ,but  i have to convert it to int and then shift it, example :

```
shift = (int(my_hex,16)<<1)
```

ok , now i have a decimal shifted , but now i need convert it to hex , when i convert it to hex by hex() i have 2 problem : 
1. how i can remove 0x in frist it ?
2. when i convert it i see character "L" at end of this decimal for example:

```
shift= (int("af5f3fee",16)<<1)
print hex(shift)
```

Result:
    before shift = af5f3fee
    after shift = 0x15ebe7fdcL
why  ?

can i shift left or right hex in python with a easy way or method ?

Comment: can't you simply multiply by 2?

Comment: the result 0x15ebe7fdcL is right! use `print hex(shift)[2:-1]` to print just the bytes hex

Comment: thanks Max , resolve by your help

Answer (score 2):

Use `format(shift,'x')` instead of `hex(shift)`

```
print format(int("af5f3fee",16)*2,'x')
```

results in `'15ebe7fdc'`

Comment: perfect !!!!!!!!!! thanks  it work . if i want shift a hex with len 400 character for example , what'is resolve way ?

Comment: you could split it in substrings of the biggest size you can transfer to an integer at once. then shift them. But you need to handle the overflow then. If your resulting string starts with '1...' you have to cut it off and add it to the next one.